# Can we change request origin header to its parent domain using document.domain?

Tags: ajax, cors, same-origin-policy

**Scenario:** Want to access content of xyz.example.com from mysubdomain.example.com (using Fetch or XMLHttpRequest).

But CORS is configured in such a way that when ORIGIN(in request header) is "example.com" then only xyz.example.com supplies ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN (with value example.com) and thus able to read its content. But by-default when I am making request from mysubdomain.example.com then origin is set to mysubdomain.example.com and thus not able to read contents of xyz.example.com.
Also all communication is on http only(since port difference also matters).
I am trying to use document.domain="example.com" to change my origin to example.com but it is not changing. How to access resource from other sub-domain in this scenario ?
(I am not having access to change server side code on xyz.example.com)

Comment: No, there’s no way to change the origin value; it is set by the browser and controlled completely by the browser.